# What is difference between pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_trylock()

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am writing an application using parallel programming and want to use synchronization. What is difference between `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_trylock()` and when should I use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lock` blocks and only returns when it has the lock, `trylock` returns immediately and can either succeed or fail to obtain the lock.

A [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_trylock) can usually answer such questions.

Comment: I did understand this basic difference but whats the difference in the sense that when to use which.?

Comment: The questions you have to ask yourself are: Can I afford to wait for the lock? Is it okay if I don't obtain the lock (because I can retry later or because I have a way of doing the work without needing the lock)? When you answer those questions, it should be fairly clear which one you want.

Comment: @VallabhPatade: Use the blocking one when you need the lock unconditionally. Use the nonblocking one when you don't want to wait and have an alternative thing to do when you can't get the lock.

Comment: If you have to ask, you probably want lock, not trylock.